# Enumerator of a lists object property

Tags: c#, list, oop

Is it possible to create a `IEnumerable` variable  that Points foreach element of another List to a specific Property?

```
//...
  SomeList<classA> MainList = new SomeList<classA>();
  IEnumerable<string> InnerList = ??MainList??;
  MainList.add(new classA());
  Console.Writeline(InnerList.First());
// ->"Hello World"
//...

class classA{
  public string innerObject = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Related Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/303/select-transforming-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via linq:

```
var sampleList = new List<classA>();

var innerList = sampleList.Select(x => x.innerObject) //This creates an IEnumerable of all innerObjects in the original list
```